# Token Expiration time - Authentication Security Check in IBM MF8

Tags: authentication, oauth, ibm-mobilefirst, access-token

I wanted to know how the access token expiration works when I am accessing a set of resources scoped for a security check.

I am using userLogin SecurityCheck  - "accessSecure"

```
@OAuthSecurity(scope="accessSecure")
```

I am using it to authenticate 4 resources in the same or different adapters.

```
.../getDate
.../getValue
.../getType
.../getRules
```

I am setting token expiration time to be 7200.

How is this expiration time calculated? Is it like within 7200 ms I can access all these resources. After 7200 ms time out happens.

Or is it like each time I access a resource, from that time 7200 ms count starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option you've suggested is the correct one:

> Is it like within 7200 ms I can access all these resources. After 7200 ms time out happens.

The expiration is counted against once you've obtained the access token. Once it is reached, it expires.